# HTML class name containing spces?

Tags: html, css

can we set a class name for HTML tag containing some spaces like this

```
<div class="drag-down drag-here">
this is the body part .. 
</div>
.
```

Comment: In short: yes, you can

Comment: There are two classes, actually

Comment: For the css selector, use .drag-down.drag-here ; if you're also using id then #someid.drag-down.drag-here

Comment: @Morpheus .. can we.? but as per the next comment does it mean that we have two class names. ?

Comment: @Vignesh Gopalakrishnan you can target in css like this `.drag-down.drag-here`. Note no space

Comment: a class name cannot have spaces. class="drag-down drag-here" = 2 classes, "drag-down" AND "drag-here"

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808846/html-class-attribute-with-spaces-it-is-a-w3c-valid-class

Comment: @Nic .. Haven't seen it . My mistake ..

Comment: @AzDesign yeah got it now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both of these classes are separate then your **class attribute** can contain these two classes separated by space. But if you are trying to create a class name with **SPACE** then it is not as per standards and will not work.
Even if you try to enter then browser will treat **drag-down** and **drag-here** as separate classes and not a single one.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is to specify multiple classes.

This way separates the class names with a space, i.e. `<htmlTag class="class1 class2">` or `<div class="drag-down drag-here">` allows you to combine several CSS classes for one HTML element.

**Naming rules:**

1. Must begin with a letter `A-Z` or `a-z`

2.Can be followed by: `letters (A-Za-z)`, `digits (0-9)`, `hyphens ("-")`, and `underscores ("_")`

3.In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

The above rule doesn't mention a `space`   so no space allowed to name a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Classes can be whateve you want, but a space means a different class name. In your case, two classes: `drag-down` & `drag-here`

Comment: then if we give it a two class name .. how can a Css file access the elements within the class names. ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Class names can not have spaces in between. The space mentioned in your code describes that 2 different CSS classes are added to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the HTML from your question *is valid*. However, it is interpreted as two seperate class names:

- `drag-down`
- `drag-here`

because a space seperates multiple class names. Unlike the `id` attribute, the `class` attribute can contain multiple values.

So, when using for instance CSS, styling rules targeted at `div.drag-down` and `div.drag-here` will both be applied to this element.

Also see the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Comment: if treated as two separate classes then can we use either of the class names in CSS .. will it work .?

Comment: Yes, it will. But you can also create CSS rules for both classes. The element will inherit the CSS of both classes (unless there is a conflict, for instance when the first class has a red background and the second class has a blue background)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="drag-down drag-here">
```

Means the div has two classes `drag-down` and `drag-here`. You can have any number of classes separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Yha sure,You can give space between the class name,

Also Refer this link [**SPACE BETWEEN CLASS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808846/html-class-attribute-with-spaces-it-is-a-w3c-valid-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple classes, seperated by a space, but a given class name cannot contain spaces.

Please refer to [**HTML class Attribute**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp)

Answer (score -1):

spaces cannot be used! better use an underscore like this:

```
<div class="drag-down_drag-here">
this is the body part .. 
</div>
```